# Regex to one letter and character without special chars

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a regex to validate below conditions in a password string

- Atleast one number and a letter
- Should not contain any special characters

Tried this regex

```
[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*|[0-9]+[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

But it allows special characters. 
Any help would be appreciated!

**Example**

- aaaa - Not accepted
- 11111 - Not accepted
- aaaa1 - Accepted
- aaaa1* - Not accepted

Comment: You may **greatly** benefit from [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922/reference-password-validation/)

Comment: Can't you just(tm)(r) start with
    `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`?

Comment: (?=.*[A-Za-z].*)(?=.*\d.*)[A-Za-z0-9]+

Comment: @MohammedElhag This is worked. And i just added ^ at start and $ at end
^(?=.*[A-Za-z].*)(?=.*\d.*)[A-Za-z0-9]+$

Comment: Your example does not correspond to your requirement. In your requirement "Atleast one number or a letter" when in your example you have "Atleast one number and a letter"

Comment: Edited requirement. @vincrichaud Thanks for finding out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this Regex:

```
(?=.*\d.*)(?=.*[a-zA-Z].*)[0-9A-Za-z]+
```

The first two sections will promise you one number and one a-z characters and the third section allows you to insert numbers or a-z characters.

Comment: I think this will have the same problems as OPs expression regarding special characters!? If not why not?

Comment: You don't need additional `.*` in your lookaheads, additional computation for literally nothing. Instead, shorten (and improve performance) by using `(?=\D*\d)(?=[^a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])[0-9A-Za-z]+`

Answer (score 0):

You could make a regex that check first the first character, if it is a letter `^[a-zA-Z]`, then expect an unknown number of alphanum char `[a-zA-Z0-9]*`. Then expect at least one number `[0-9]+` and finally expect another unknow number of of alphanum until the end `[a-zA-Z0-9]*$`. This look like :

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

Make the equivalent if it starts with a number `^[0-9]`, then expect an unknown number of alphanum char `[a-zA-Z0-9]*`. Then expect at least one letter `[a-zA-Z]+` and finally expect another unknow number of of alphanum until the end `[a-zA-Z0-9]*$`. This look like :

```
^[0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

And make a OR betwenn this two regex :

```
^( [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9]* | [0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*) $
```

Answer (score -1):

Your pattern should start with `^` (beginning of string) and end with `$` (end of string). I assume your check succeeds if it finds an occurence of the pattern.

So it should be

```
^([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*|[0-9]+[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*)$
```

Comment: No, this is wrong `^[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*|[0-9]+[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$`. You should be more specific.

Comment: @ctwheels Ok I edited to make it unmistakable what I meant. Before, you are right, it was a little ambiguous. And, as you correctly observed, just prepending ^ and appending $ is wrong because of the disjunction.